# What is wrong with my malloc declaration?

Tags: c, arrays

I have written the following code. The thing is that when it enters the internal loop the program stacks and so the input procedure stops. Have I done something wrong?

What I do here is create an array of pointers, and each pointer points to an array - each array of different size. Then the even numbered lines take only one number, while the odd numbered lines take more.

```
long int K,i,j; 
scanf("%ld", &K);   

long int **pl_r;
pl_r = (long int **) malloc(2*K*sizeof(long int *));              

for(i=0; i<K; i++)
{
    pl_r[2*i] = (long int *) malloc(1 *sizeof(long int));
    scanf("%ld", &pl_r[2*i][0]);
    pl_r[2*i+1] = (long int *) malloc(pl_r[2*i][0] *sizeof(long int));
    scanf("%ld", &pl_r[2*i+1][0]);
    for(j=1; j<pl_r[2*i][0]-1; i++){
        scanf("%ld", &pl_r[2*i+1][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3425536)

Comment: If this is C, don't cast `malloc`. If this is C++, use `std::vector`, etc. (in other words, the languages are *not* the same).

Comment: Your first malloc should use `sizeof( long int * )` as you're storing `long int *`s in that memory, not `long int`s.

Comment: There's nothing in this question to suggest that C++ is being used, so I'll remove the tag.

Comment: It looks like you also need room for 2*K `long int *`s. IE `malloc( 2*K*sizeof( long int * ) )`

Comment: I fixed both Paulpro's observations. thanks a lot! though, still it does not work

Comment: One more precision, what is your compile command and/or makefile?

Comment: I use dev to write and compile the program

Comment: the problem is i put i in the loop instead of j -.-    you may erase this question...

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have included `<stdlib.h>` to avoid any warning when you don't cast with `malloc`, because you **should not** cast with `malloc` if I'm not mistaken.

Then to avoid confusion between pointers and pointers of pointers when allocating memory you can do this

```
pl_r = malloc(K * sizeof *pl_r);
```

Comment: The first and last paragraphs are unnecessary. Your answer is correct.

Comment: When I write this it does not compile:  invalid conversion from 'void*' to long int**'

Comment: @lea You're compiling C as C++. Choose one. Because in C++ you *need* to cast the result of `malloc`, but in C you shouldn't cast it. In C `void*` is automatically converted to any other pointer type.

Comment: Couldn't this be because `K` was not input correctly? What if you hard code  `K` ? for instance `K = 1;`

Comment: yes you're right. it compiled as a c file. but the input still stops in the internal loop...

Comment: i don t understand what you mean aduch

Comment: It might not be the problem, but what I was asking you to try, was to replace `scanf("%ld", &K);` by `K = 1;`

Comment: i tried what you said for K=1000 (even if this is not the input the program must take) but it still does the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3425536). As for the question, the first `malloc` should be:

```
pl_r = malloc(K*sizeof(long int *))
                                ^ this is missing
```

Comment: it's true. thanks a lot, though it still does not work